# What is the point in the mnemonic פמג"ש ממקגט"י ככסע"ז?

Tags: talmud-bavli, bava-metzia, memory

In Bava Metzia 21b, there is a mnemonic given which I find quite odd - פמג"ש ממקגט"י ככסע"ז .  See http://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.21b.18?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all

The way I see it, the point in mnemonics is to help people remember things.  eg. Detzach Adash Beachav helps remember the names of the plagues. In this case, the mnemonic seems particularly difficult to pronounce, let alone remember, so it doesn't seem to be doing a very good job.  Not only that, but what is the particular importance of remembering these cases?  The Gemarah doesn't make such widespread use of mnemonics all of the place as far as I am aware so why here?

Comment: It's a pretty long Sugya so this helps us remember. What's wrong with a mnemonic?

Comment: If you would have said pamgash mamkagti kikasaz as many times as you've said ditzach adash biachav the words would suddenly no longer sound strange and would serve as a wonderful mnemonic.

Comment: OK, I've hunted around the meforshim. Can't locate what the mnemonic means. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it really help us remember?  pamgash mamkagti kikasaz seems an order of magnitude harder to remember than detzach adash beachav, but anyway, what's the specific importance of having to remember these cases?  I'm not incredibly well learned, but I have been through enough sugyas over the years (maybe around 10-15) to know that it isn't usual for mnemonics to be used - I don't recall seeing any others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar passages can be found in all shas. You rapidly can see dozen, this is particularly length. The particularity is that this sugia treat a simple topic with a long list of similar Ta Shma (an attempt to solve the problem with a Brayta or a Mishna). It is relatively rare from a formal point of view 

I think that is the list of Ta Shma of the suggia of Yeush Shelo Midaat. Here is a first attempt. Correction is welcome. there are 12 Ta shma, here are 15 letters, I included somewhat after the Tiuvta deRava.

P--> Perot 
M--> Maot
G --> iGulim
Sh --> leSHonot
M --> Maot

M --> Meematay
Q --> Ktsiot
G --> Ganav
T --> shaTaf nahar
Y --> Yarad letoch sade/ Yafot
K --> Ki yutan
K --> Ken Taase
S --> Siman
Ayn --> ya"A"l kegam

Z --> tamre deZika

Comment: Looks like he knows that but is asking why they bothered coming up with this.

Comment: @HaLeiVi to know the Tashmaym binshima ahat is good. notrikun is like this. When you need to know very promptly It is the best way. Students in exam also use this BTW the mnemonic is right.

Comment: @HaLeiVi "אמר רב חסדא:אין תורה נקנית אלא בסימנים" [wiki](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/סימנים_(תלמוד))

Comment: @kouty but what is so special about this sugya that they came up with a siman for it?  I've not come across that before in Gemarah.

Comment: @wizzardmr42    Similar passages can be found in all shas. you rapidly can see dozen, this is particularly length. The particularity is that ths sugia is a simple topic with a long list of similar tashma. It is relatively rare from a formal point of view

Comment: @HaLeiVi **ס"ע** סמוך עניים **ל"א סימנין עשה בתורה וקנה אותה**. http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.104a.25?with=all

Comment: A gmara in Eruvin 5e chapter...?

Comment: @kouty Thanks.  I think that your penultimate comment pretty much answers my question.  If you post it as an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: @wizzardmr42 fixed